# How to check if a string is a substring of any element in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", \
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", \
    "November", "December"];
```

I have strings like "Nov", "October", "Jun", "June", "Sept", "Sep" etc. The point is, the string can be a substring of one of the months.

What is the best way to compare the string to be a substring of the array elements? How do I find out the index of the month?

I am looking at javascript/jQuery.

I know I can just loop through the array checking against each element using `search` and break when found. I want something better.

Comment: It's not too difficult to do manually. What have you tried?

Comment: You can use `Array#forEach` but ultimately you'll _need_ to loop through the array.

Comment: I need the index also, so Array#some won't work.

Comment: @JanDvorak Array#forEach returns a modified array.

Comment: What's wrong with iterating over each item in the array and making the comparison? What do you mean by "better"? Shorter code? More efficient?

Comment: Shorter code, maybe a one-liner... similar to Array#some but returning an index...

Comment: have you tried a combination of 'inArray' and 'indexOf'?

Comment: @SvenBieder Does inArray check substring? I don't think so.

Comment: @ATOzTOA who has said that it does? that is why I said a combination of inArray and indexOf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var month_index = function(target) {
        target = target.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return jQuery.inArray(true, jQuery.map(months, function(s) {
            return s.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(target) > -1;
        }))
    };

var index_of_october = month_index("oct");
```

Comment: @flem: indexOf looks for a substring and returns the index if found, -1 if not. Also, updated it to be locale-sensitive and case-insensitive.

Comment: What is the output of this?

Comment: @ATOzTOA: index_of_october is 9. Try it out in Firebug's console.

Answer (score 2):

```
var  substr = 'nov', months = ["december", "november", "feb"];

var index = months.indexOf( months.filter(function(v){ return v.indexOf(substr) >= 0;})[0]);
alert(index)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KeMe9/

Answer (score 0):

Put your array items in lower case

```
var txt = "Sep";
var found = false;
txt = txt.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (months[i].indexOf(txt) > -1) {
        found = true;
        break;
  }
}
```