# Check if string element contains string in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

I am using jQuery to check if a string is contained in any of the strings in an array like so -

```
var arrayText = ["the","cat","sat"];
arrayText.indexOf($('#textBox1').val()) > -1)
```

However this only appears to match exact cases, however is it possible to change it so that it matches part matches, e.g. "he" is present in "the" therefore the result would be greater than -1?

Comment: You'll probably need a regex for this instead.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/14024837/1181310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work for you

```
var arrayText = ["the", "cat", "sat"];
if ($.grep(arrayText, function (e, i) {
    return /at/i.test(e);
}).length > 0) {
    console.log('matched')
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6rxWf/134/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find whether an array has an element which is a sub-string of another string then ;

```
var arrayText = ["the","cat","sat"];

Array.prototype.containsSubString = function( text ){
    for ( var i in this )
    {
        if ( this[i].toString().indexOf( text ) != -1 )
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

if( arrayText.containsSubString( 'he' ) !== -1) 
{
    alert("Found in arrayText !");
}
```